# How to insert NaN in an array if it is missing values that are present in another array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Assume I have two arrays:

```
A = [850;950;1000;1050;1100];
B = [850;950;1000;1100];
```

Here `B` is missing the value `1050` that is present in array `A`. As I later would like to compare `A` and `B` logically I would like to fill this missing place with a `NaN` thus giving me

```
B = [850;950;1000;NaN;1100];
```

What is the fastest way to do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a copy of `A`, and NaN out any values which aren't a member of `B`. This is easier than inserting NaNs in the correct places of B...

```
C = A;
C( ~ismember( A, B ) ) = NaN;
```

Optionally, you can assign `B = C` at the end.

Alternatively you can avoid copying all of `A`, and just assign the index to a variable, this is purely a preference thing...

```
idx = ~ismember( A, B );
B = A;
B( idx ) = NaN;
```